# Eat space in a line break in \lstinline{}

Tags: formatting, listings

I use the `listings` package. If a line break inside a multi-word `\lstinline{}` occurs, I get a nasty spaces at the beginning of the new line:

```
page left                  page right
    |                          |   
    |normal text normal text IF|
    | FORALL normal text       |
```

`IF FORALL` is inside a `\lstinline{}`.

How to avoid the space before `FORALL`?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: I don't mind to elaborate. I am typing a document that includes some inline code snippets. I use `\lstinline{}` to typeset them (since I also use `lstlisting` in my document).

The illustration above depicts the result from latex code:

```
normal text normal text \lstinline{IF FORALL} normal text
```

Now if `IF FORALL` does fit into a single line, I get

```
    |normal text normal text IF FORALL normal|
    |text                                    |
```

on my page, which is fine. The `|` mark the start of the page margin.

If `IF FORALL` is broken down into multiple lines, I get the result shown above. I would much rather like to have:

```
    |normal text normal text IF|
    |FORALL normal text        |
```

Hope that this makes it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Start by posting a minimal example of what you are doing.

Comment: Let me know if this makes it more clear

Comment: This is a lot better.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently not implemented at this time.

Answer (score 3):

The space is the one between the IF and the FORALL. I don't know if it is possible to eat it somehow, but you can at least move a bit back:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines,postbreak=\kern-1ex}
\textwidth=4cm
\parindent=0cm
\begin{document}
normal text normal text \lstinline{IF FORALL} normal text
\end{document}
```

Addition: I just realized, that the space disappears too if you use
     \lstset{breaklines,breakatwhitespace}

Addition 2: An obvious solution which avoids all this hassle with the white space is to use two \lstinline commands: \lstinline{IF} \lstinline{FORALL}.

Comment: @Ulrike: Your first solution doesn't work: `-1ex` isn't quite correct, but that's not the main problem. If you increase the text width to `4.3cm`, then "IF " fits on the first line, and the second line starts with "FORALL", moved to the left by -1ex. That's definitely not desired. Your second solutions seems to work perfectly, at least with a recent TeX installation! So could you please replace your first solution with the second one?

Comment: Well no: the second doesn't work perfectly either, as then (with textwidth=4.3cm) the first line is a bit to short (the space behind the IF is there). The perfect solution is postbreak=\kern-1ex when the break is before the space and prebreak=\kern-1ex if the break is after the space.

Comment: Oh my, you're right, the `breakatwhitespace` option doesn't solve the problem either. To me this seems like a bug in the package. Anyway, this `breakatwhitespace` isn't well documented. Still your `\kern-1ex` isn't perfect, but it's not clear how to make it better: It seems that the width of the white space varies depending on the letters around it. So at the moment, your "Addition 2" seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question per se, but what I do is either rewrite the text so that the listing fits on a single line, or if that is not possible for whatever reason, then make it a nonfloating listing. This takes a little extra space, but I think it is more readable than having it break.